# Correct user approach on deleting fields with dependencies

Tags: mongodb, algorithm, mongoose, database-design, user-experience

I'm building an IoT application that will have some configuration screens to setup a process flow. For each step of the process flow the system will collect automated data regarding each process step's start time, end time, duration, location, etc., that will then build several KPI's and indicators.

Inm general I have the following data schema (using a custom metadata):

```
processStep: {
   id: ID
   name: string,
   owner: user_id,
   ...
}

process: {
   id: ID
   name: string, 
   sequence: [
        processStep_id: ID
   ]
   ...
}

executionSteps {
   id: ID,
   process_id: ID,
   processSteps_id: ID,
   startDateTime: timestamp,
   endDateTime: timestamp, 
   duration: interval,
   ...
}

efficiency: {
   id: ID,
   day: int
   month: int,
   year: int,
   hour: int
   level: float
   ...
}
```

`efficiency` is calculated based on `executionSteps` data on a hourly batch, and `executionSteps` follows the sequence configured at `process` and `processSteps`.

All done in a mongo database using mongoose.

I'm now designing a delete record approach for the user. I'm using soft deletes for all documents schemas, using a `deletedAt` field (when 0, says the field is not deleted. If `deletedAt` has a timestamp, than the document is deleted).

My doubt is related on how to handle customer and data in case of objects deletion.

If I delete a `processStep`, all `process` objects that has the deleted `processStep_id` on its sequence will be invalidated. The same way, `executionSteps` and `efficiency` will also be invalidated, in a complete and typical dependency chain.

In a practical case after one year of system usage, if the user deletes a `processStep` I can be forced to invalidate all efficiency statistics of the system, as all records related to that chain shall be delete also.

My question is the correct strategy to handle this situation:

a) Warn the user what is gonna be hapenning if he deletes a basic element and let it decide consequences (changes efficiency indexes and delete several records) ?

b) Don't allow the user to delete the root element until he deletes all dependency records ? That case seens unfeasable as the user cannot delete `efficiency` statistics, as it is composed of several elements.

c) Soft delete the root element (`processStep` and `processes`) and still keep alive the `executionSteps` and `efficiency`. In that case I will have information gap if the user starts to detail the efficiency data (via drill down, what he can do).

I'm really confused on how option to choose, or even if there is a better approach to that.

Help to understand the correct approach for the best user experience.

Comment: I would suggest a warning to the user followed by cascading soft deletes.  Since `efficiency` isn't linked back to anything (as far as I can see) that won't cause any discrepancies.